# Realm.io: Sync or Async?

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have a function `sync`, which runs periodically, to synchronize all un-unsynchronized Realm models (I use this `sync` flag internally in my application, just to check if I already processed the model or not).

I used NSLock as a protection, because can happen that `sync` run multiple times simultaneously.

I'm having a problem that sometimes the same models are processed multiple times.
I would like to know if theres any problem in my code, and how can I fix it (I think it may be due realm.io could be asynchronous).

---

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLock *lock;

- (void)sync
{
    if (![self.lock tryLock]) return;

    RLMResults *models = [Model objectsWhere:@"sync = 0"];
    for (Model *model in models) {

        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        model.sync = 1; // 1 step - Required to run the function.
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];

        [self myFunc]; // 2 step.

    [self.lock unlock];
}

- (void)myFunc
{
    NSLog(@"Updating view controller."):
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you don't need to store the property `sync` in your database persistently, you can also add it to your `ignoredProperties`, then you won't need a write transaction at all.

If you have a good reason to store it there, you could also use the write transaction as implicit locking mechanism.

We recommend with Realm to favor grouping write transactions to large batches instead of a lot small transactions. That's because our [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) needs to retain all versions which are still accessed by a thread, which wasn't updated yet.

In advance I interpret that the sync method does actually some more work, instead of just toggling the `sync` flag and that `myFunc` is updating the view controllers with fresh data. If the `sync` method can be run multiple times simultaneously, it must be called asynchronously / run from another thread, because the main queue is not concurrent. While `myFunc` must run on the main thread, because you can only update your UI from there. This excludes it to share the same Realm instance between these two methods as the accessors are not thread-safe. If you trigger updates for your UI from another thread's Realm instance inside of a big batched write transaction in the sync method, then the model updates aren't visible yet. So you would need to batch the UI updates as well.

```
- (void)sync {
    if (realm.inWriteTransaction) {
        return;
    }
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    RLMResults *models = [Model objectsWhere:@"sync = 0"];
    NSArray *modelIds = [models valueForKey:@"primaryKey"];
    for (Model *model in models) {
        model.sync = 1; // 1st step.
        // More expensive background work happens here?
    }
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    // Asynchronous batched 2nd step.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self myFuncWithUpdatedModelIds:modelIds];
    });
}
```

Comment: Small thing: `[realm.inWriteTransaction]` should be `[realm inWriteTransaction]`.